# How can I add stitches to my model using only texture technique?

Tags: texturing, uv

In order to model socks, I want to add stitches and change the UV in a different part of the model based on the reference picture.
I don't know where to begin.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to model the socks flat, as shown?

Comment: No, I try to figure out the best approach.

I tried sewing it, but had a hard time getting a good result.
A recent attempt I made was to model it around a foot: